# What language is used to develop spiceworks desktop IT software?

Tags: programming-languages, spiceworks

What language/Technologies are used to develop [Spiceworks](http://www.spiceworks.com)?

How did they archive that, its like a desktop app running inside a browser, actually it has its own webserver!

I am very curious on how they pulled this one off, because if you check in the installation directory you can't find HTML files or CSS files?

Comment: This almost sounds like a stealth ad for the software (quick -- what's the first thing you did when you read this question never having heard of this 'SpiceWorks' thing).  Not saying it is, but I'm curious if that would work....

Answer (score 2):

Spiceworks is written in Ruby.

Source: https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/programming-and-development/?p=350

On a side note, they have a really nice UI!

Answer (score 0):

There's a [contact link](http://www.spiceworks.com/contact/) on their web page. I'm not sure why you'd think we would know more about their product than them.

There's no requirement for a web server to pull its content out of individual files. They could be held in one big file and extracted as required, or even in the executable as strings for all we know.

I suggest you ask them.